# how to configure spring-boot JAR java application in intelliJ with external conf

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I got a java application that I build in jar, and which runs with the cmd command and the jar.

but I can't make it run with IntelliJ, I have bean problems in jar config and application.
My properties files are external files external to the project.

in IntelliJ i have Cannot resolve reference to bean

ApplicationContext.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <bean id="propertyPlaceholderConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>file:///etc/chl/myapp/myapp-commun.properties</value>
                <value>file:///etc/chl/myapp/myapp-snmp.properties</value>
                <value>file:///etc/chl/myapp/app-lst.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="tmpFileName" class="java.lang.String">
        <constructor-arg value="${app.filename.tmp}" />
    </bean>
    
    <bean id="dstFileName" class="java.lang.String">
        <constructor-arg value="${myapp.lst}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="fetcher" class="com.myapp.mylist.mylistFetcher"
        p:mylistUrl="${app.mylist.url}"
        p:trustStore="${app.truststore}" p:trustStorePass="${app.truststore.password}"
        p:targetFileName="${app.filename.tmp}" />

    <bean id="wlAnchors" class="fr.myapp.utils.tls.X509Tools" factory-method="loadFromFile">
        <constructor-arg value="${app.validator.anchors}" />
        <constructor-arg value="${app.validator.anchors.password}" />
    </bean>
    
    <bean id="wlInterm" class="fr.myapp.utils.tls.X509Tools" factory-method="keystoreToList">
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean class="fr.myapp.utils.tls.X509Tools" factory-method="loadFromFile">
                <constructor-arg value="${app.validator.inter.ca}" />
                <constructor-arg value="${app.validator.inter.ca.password}" />
            </bean>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
    
    <bean id="crls" class="fr.myapp.utils.tls.X509Tools" factory-method="loadFromPath">
        <constructor-arg value="${myapp.asip.crlPath}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="validator" class="fr.myapp.mylist.mylistValidator"
        p:checkKeyUsage="${app.validator.checkKeyUsage}"
        p:checkRevocation="${app.validator.checkRevocation}"
        p:validateSchema="${app.validator.validateSchema}"
        p:targetFileName="${app.filename.tmp}" 
        p:trustAnchors-ref="wlAnchors"
        p:intermediateCAs-ref="wlInterm"
        p:crls-ref="crls" />

    <bean id="processor" class="fr.myapp.mylist.mylistProcessor" >
        <property name="processeurs">
            <list>
                <ref bean="mxFingerprint"/>
                <bean class="fr.myapp.mylist.processors.PostfixDomainAccessGenerator"
                    p:accessFilename="${app.mail.access}"
                    p:postmapPath="${app.mail.postmapCommand}" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="ldapConnectionFactory" class="org.ldaptive.DefaultConnectionFactory"
        p:provider-ref="ldapProvider"
        p:connectionConfig-ref="ldapConnectionConfig" />

    <bean id="ldapConnectionConfig" class="org.ldaptive.ConnectionConfig"
        p:ldapUrl="${app.ldap.url}" >
        <property name="connectionStrategy">
                <bean class="org.ldaptive.RandomConnectionStrategy" />
        </property>
        <property name="connectTimeout">
                <bean class="java.time.Duration" factory-method="ofMillis">
                    <constructor-arg value="${app.ldap.connectTimeout}" />
                </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="responseTimeout">
                <bean class="java.time.Duration" factory-method="ofMillis">
                    <constructor-arg value="${app.ldap.responseTimeout}" />
                </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="ldapProvider" class="org.ldaptive.provider.unboundid.UnboundIDProvider"
        p:providerConfig-ref="ldapProviderConfig" />

    <bean id="ldapProviderConfig" class="org.ldaptive.provider.unboundid.UnboundIDProviderConfig"
        p:connectionOptions-ref="ldapConnectionOptions"
        p:socketFactory-ref="ldapSocketFactory" />

    <bean id="ldapConnectionOptions" class="com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.LDAPConnectionOptions"
        p:abandonOnTimeout="true" />

    <bean id="ldapSocketFactory" class="javax.net.DefaultSocketFactory" />

    <!-- Beans du matériel cryptographique -->
    <bean id="anchors" class="fr.myapp.utils.tls.X509Tools" factory-method="loadFromFile">
        <constructor-arg value="${app.ldap.x509.truststore}" />
        <constructor-arg value="${app.ldap.x509.truststore.password}" />
    </bean>
    
    <bean id="interm" class="fr.myapp.utils.tls.X509Tools" factory-method="keystoreToList">
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean class="fr.myapp.utils.tls.X509Tools" factory-method="loadFromFile">
                <constructor-arg value="${app.ldap.x509.intermediate.ca}" />
                <constructor-arg value="${app.ldap.x509.intermediate.ca.password}" />
            </bean>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <bean id="mxFingerprint" class="fr.myapp.mylist.processors.MXFingerprintsFetchByLdapAndProcess"
        p:binaryAttribute="userCertificate"
        p:digestType="SHA-1"
        p:ldapFilter="${app.ldap.filter}" 
        p:ldapConnectionFactory-ref="ldapConnectionFactory" 
        p:checkCertificate="${app.ldap.x509.validate}"
        p:anchors-ref="anchors"
        p:interm-ref="interm"
        p:crls-ref="crls"
        p:checkRevocation="${app.ldap.x509.checkRevocation}" >      
        
        <property name="fingerprintProcessors">
            <list>
                <bean class="fr.myapp.fingerprints.processors.PostfixTlsPolicyFingerprintProcessor" 
                    p:tlsPolicyFilename="${app.mail.tlsPolicy}"
                    p:prefixFilename="${app.mail.tlsPolicy.prefix}" 
                    p:postmapPath="${app.mail.postmapCommand}" />
            </list>
        </property>     
    </bean> 

    <bean id="notifier" class="fr.util.notifiers.impl.SnmpV2TrapNotifier"        
        p:community="${snmp.community}"
        p:trapOid="${snmp.oid.trap.lst}"
        p:statusOid="${snmp.oid.status}"
        p:msgOid="${snmp.oid.msg}"
        p:perfOid="${snmp.oid.perf}"
        p:receiver="${snmp.receiver}" />

</beans>
```

pom.xml

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>myapp-parent</groupId>
        <artifactId>myapp-parent</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>myapp-lst</artifactId>
    <version>0.2.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>example</name>
    <description></description>

    <properties>
        <plugin.download.version>1.4.1</plugin.download.version>
        <santuario.version>2.1.2</santuario.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>com.myapp-parent.myapp.mylist.app.ConsoleApp</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.googlecode.maven-download-plugin</groupId>
                <artifactId>download-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${plugin.download.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>CRL-IGC-ELEM-ORG</id>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wget</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <url>**url**</url>
                            <outputFileName>ACI-EL-ORG.crl</outputFileName>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/crls</outputDirectory>
                            <skipCache>true</skipCache>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>CRL-IGC-ELEM</id>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wget</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <url>**url**</url>
                            <outputFileName>ACR-EL.crl</outputFileName>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/crls</outputDirectory>
                            <skipCache>true</skipCache>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>xml-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven.dependency.version}</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>

    </build>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.maven-download-plugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>download-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${plugin.download.version}</version>
            <type>maven-plugin</type>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ldaptive</groupId>
            <artifactId>ldaptive</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ldaptive</groupId>
            <artifactId>ldaptive-unboundid</artifactId>
        </dependency>
         ...
         ...
         ...
    </dependencies>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>chl-public-released</id>
            <name>releases</name>
            <url>**url**</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>chl-public-snapshots</id>
            <name>snapshots</name>
            <url>**url**</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

How to configure my idea or what should change?

To be able to run this application step to step debug mode with IntelliJ

Comment: IntelliJ "Pro" (this has full spring support) or "Community" (this has none at all/you have to configure)?;)

Comment: IntelliJ Community , if it's possible

Comment: Configure a "run (or debug) configuration", which invokes `spring-boot:run` (Gradle/Maven) ..for debugging, you'd have to configure/hack more (remote..) .. you will still encounter bugs/limitations with springboot-devtools

Comment: So I can recommend: invest into pro edition/use STS/use (additionally) netbeans

Comment: i can use pro trial version with springboot plugin may not recognize main